# Symfony2 and composer not installing packages

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, composer-php

I'm trying to install the FOSUserBundle on Symfony2.

On trying to run this command in the Terminal

> composer update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

I am presented with this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>   your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
>       - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>   your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
>       - Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.0].

I have read about the INTL extension not being installed correct, so I followed [these instructions](http://sunny.chotai.uk.com/?p=2), restarted MAMP and the issue is still present!

I've checked with phpinfo() also and it's confirmed that INTL has been installed. I'm at a loss on how to get rid of these errors!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is still present because you are running composer update only for FOSUserBundle.

First try to run `composer update symfony/icu`, and then run `composer update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle`.

If this doesn't work, try updating all your vendors with `composer update`

Comment: I've been trying for days and your exact instructions solve it. Thank you @edwines!